# Ubuntu commands aren't working

Tags: command-line, ls

My Ubuntu seems a bit weird. `cd` and `mkdir` work fine, but instructions other than `ls` and `rm` do not. I'm not sure what the problem is. Isn't there another way to initialize this path? I have solved the problem where the terminal was not working before, but this time the instruction was not executed and I was unable to proceed with my experiment.

```
(base) sohyeon@X11DAi-N:~$ ls
(base) sohyeon@X11DAi-N:~$ ls
(base) sohyeon@X11DAi-N:~$ ls
(base) sohyeon@X11DAi-N:~$ ls
(base) sohyeon@X11DAi-N:~$ mkdir bl
(base) sohyeon@X11DAi-N:~$ cd bl
(base) sohyeon@X11DAi-N:~/bl$ ls
(base) sohyeon@X11DAi-N:~/bl$ echo $PWD
/home/sohyeon/bl
(base) sohyeon@X11DAi-N:~/bl$ ^C
(base) sohyeon@X11DAi-N:~/bl$ ls -blah
(base) sohyeon@X11DAi-N:~/bl$
```

```
(base) sohyeon@X11DAi-N:~$ type -a ls
ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto'
ls is /usr/bin/ls
ls is /bin/ls
```

Check my folder capture image.

[image]

Comment: @muru add output!

Comment: @Terrance `(base) sohyeon@X11DAi-N:~$ lsb_release -d`
`Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS`

Comment: Before that, it worked well with the (base). Is it a terminal problem?

Comment: I don't think it is a terminal problem.  Not really sure what the issue is.  I am trying to see if I can duplicate your issue.

Comment: I am wondering if the `coreutils` needs to be reinstalled which is what supplies `ls`.  `sudo apt install --reinstall coreutils`

Comment: @Terrance OMG done!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! thankyou LOL !!!!!!!1

Comment: Glad that helped!  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something is not working with the `ls` command.  Might need to be reinstalled.  To reinstall the `ls` command it is done by reinstalling the `coreutils` package.

```
sudo apt install --reinstall coreutils
```

Answer (score 5):

You've provided no Ubuntu product & release details; but if you perform a `ls` command (ie list files) in a directory which has no contents (*no files or directories; not counting any hidden files/directories*), no results are shown as there is nothing to show.

eg.

```
guiverc@d7050-ubu-lts:~$   mkdir bl
guiverc@d7050-ubu-lts:~$   cd bl
guiverc@d7050-ubu-lts:~/bl$   ls
guiverc@d7050-ubu-lts:~/bl$   echo $PWD
/home/guiverc/bl
```

I created a directory `bl`, then made in my *present working directory* ($PWD) with the `cd` command, then performed the list-directory contents (`ls`) in that *empty* directory, and it shows it was empty by the lack of results.  This is expected.

To view all details in the directory; you can add options to the `ls` command (*which will not show hidden files/directories by default*), which on the newly created directory will be

```
guiverc@d7050-ubu-lts:~/bl$   ls -lah
total 32K
drwxrwxr-x  2 guiverc guiverc 4.0K Aug  7 11:49 .
drwxrwxr-x 62 guiverc guiverc  28K Aug  7 11:49 ..
```

*ps:  I don't need all of `-lah`, but my fingers typed when I wanted to add the `-a` to show all, as I prefer reading results in *long* (`-l`) format and in *human* format too (`-h`) thus my *fingers* translated my mental `-a` to `-lah`*

My directory is actually empty (*was only recently created*), thus all mine contains is the *pointers* the system uses to '*walk the directory structure*' which is what now show.

Comment: If people wonder why `bl` ... my intention was `blah` alas it already existed due to some prior like example, thus i shortened it to `bl`

Comment: no, my forder is full. not empty..

Comment: `ls -a` `ls -lah` not working. working is `cd`, `rm` etc done..